# SQL запрос на совпадения двух слов непоследовательно

Tags: sql, запрос, поиск

Есть поиск, реализован таким образом:

```
$query_where .= " AND (a.Name LIKE '%$_GET[key]%' OR a.ImportSourceID LIKE '%$_GET[key]%')";
```

На данный момент работает так:
Есть товар с названием (a.Name) "FIAMMA Кофемашина серии Atlantic", идет поиск по словам "FIAMMA Кофемашина" или, например, "серии Atlantic", то есть по словосочетаниям, без нарушения последовательности слов. Но если ищу "FIAMMA Atlantic", то результата нет. Вопрос: можно ли построить запрос таким образом, чтобы велся поиск по непоследовательным словам?

Comment: [Полнотекстовый поиск](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch.html)?

Comment: Передавайте так: "FIAMMA%Atlantic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простейший вариант без настройки индекса: преобразовать строку со словами поисковыми

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/ /","%",$_GET[key]);
```

и уже потом запрос ставить на эту переменную